# Error during data INSERT in php

Tags: php, mysql

here my code-

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblpin ('pinId', 'ownerId', 'usedby', 'status') VALUES ";
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($pin); $i++) 
{
if ($i>0)
    {
    $sql .= ", ";
    }
$sql .= "('$pin[$i]', '$ownerid', 'Free', '1')";
}
$sql .= ";";

echo $sql;

mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
{
    echo "done";
}
else
{
    echo "Fail";
}
```

**output: ** `INSERT INTO tblpin ('pinId', 'ownerId', 'usedby', 'status') VALUES ('13837927', 'admin', 'Free', '1'), ('59576082', 'admin', 'Free', '1');`  Fail**

**why it is not inserting values when $sql query is right?**

Comment: it would be helpful if u specify the error msg its generation mysql_error()

Comment: If you're copy and pasting code, highlight it after paste and hit the little button on the editor thats all 01010 ... that will properly indent everything 4 spaces so it renders as code.

Comment: @Erik I do highlight my code but ony first line appears as code not rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here

```
INSERT INTO tblpin ('pinId', 'ownerId', 'usedby', 'status') VALUES
```

you got to use `` or use nothing to define table and rows but you cant use '' instead so the right query will be:

```
INSERT INTO `tblpin` (`pinId`, `ownerId`, `usedby`, `status`) VALUES ('13837927', 'admin', 'Free', '1'), ('59576082', 'admin', 'Free', '1');
```

OR:

```
INSERT INTO tblpin (pinId, ownerId, usedby, status) VALUES ('13837927', 'admin', 'Free', '1'), ('59576082', 'admin', 'Free', '1');
```

Comment: but if I am not generating sql query dynamically but passing it as it is, it is working fine?? why.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put your column names between quotes.

Comment: Use backticks for column names -- ie `\`pidID\`, \`ownerId\``

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tblpin (pinId, ownerId, usedby, status) VALUES (13837927, 'admin', 'Free', 1), (59576082, 'admin', 'Free', 1);
```